# O erro na impressão de números em C

Tags: c

O erro é que a impressão dos números esta aparecendo duplicada.

Enunciado:
[image: Enunciado da questão]

A mensagem de erro:
[image: erro]

O código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int maiorValor(int *array[], int *q);
 
int main()
{
    int N, k;
    int vetor[] = {0};
    
    printf("Qual o tamanho do array: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Quantos valores por linha: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    
    fflush(stdin);
    
    for(int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        vetor[r] = rand()%99;
    }
    
    int res = maiorValor(vetor, N);
    
    for(int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        for(int l = 0; l < k; l++)
        {
            printf("%d  ", vetor[r]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("\nO maior valor foi: %d", res);
    return 0;
}
 
int maiorValor(int *array[], int *q)
{
    int maior = array[0];
    for(int r = 0; r < q; r++)
    {
        if(array[r] > maior)
        {
            maior = array[r];
        }
    }
    return (maior);
}
```

Comment: Tem que usar ponteiros neste codigo? Testei tem uns problemas com os ponteiros? No codigo ```rand()%99``` gera valores ate 98, mas pela imagem dar pra ver valores bem maiores

Comment: Cara, para mim não tá muito claro o que está duplicado... É o que está sendo impresso dentro do for? Se for isso, basta retirar o for... Já tentaste debugar, vendo passo a passo o que está ocorrendo...

Comment: Além disso, tu estás alocando um vetor de um único espaço, em vez de alocar um vetor com o tamanho de elementos desejado

Comment: Eu não entendi o que vc quis dizer com "vetor de um único espaço".

Comment: Seu ponteiro so é suficiente para armazenar um unico valor inteiro, e não um vetor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int maiorValor(int array[], int q);

int main()
{
    int N = 1, k;
    
    printf("Qual o tamanho do array: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int vetor[N];
    printf("Quantos valores por linha: ");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    
    fflush(stdin);
    
    for(int r = 0; r < N; r++)
    {
        vetor[r] = rand()%99;
    }
    
    int res = maiorValor(vetor, N);
    
    for(int r = 0; r < N; r++)
{
    printf("%d  ", vetor[r]);

    if (((r+1) % k) == 0) //Verifica se r+1 é múltiplo inteiro de k
    {
        printf("\n"); //Se for, pula linha
    }           
}
printf("\nO maior valor foi: %d", res);
return 0;
}
int maiorValor(int array[], int q)
{
    int maior = array[0];
    for(int r = 0; r < q; r++)
    {
        if(array[r] > maior)
        {
            maior = array[r];
        }
    }
    return (maior);
}
```

Comment: não esta duplicando, mas continua aparecendo valores absurdos.

Comment: Removeu os ponteiros? Esses numeros "absurdos" é por conta dos ponteiro que foram mau alocados

Comment: Removi os ponteiro e adicionei o trecho de código que pula linha. Ainda aparecem valores absurdos. O que resolveu foi declarar int vetor após a entrada do valor N, que eu já tinha feito, mas que tinha outras partes do código erradas. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Não está apenas duplicado, seu código imprime o mesmo valor `k` vezes, no seguinte trecho:

```
for(int l = 0; l < k; l++)
{
    printf("%d  ", vetor[r]);
}
```

Para corrigir, use lógica modular, assim:

```
for(int r = 0; r < N; r++)
{
    printf("%d  ", vetor[r]);

    if (((r+1) % k) == 0) //Verifica se r+1 é múltiplo inteiro de k
    {
        printf("\n"); //Se for, pula linha
    }           
}
```

Observe que agora é necessário validar a entrada `k` para que não seja zero.